# Running macro with vbscript - workbook on shared drive

Tags: excel, vbscript, vba

Good morning,

I'm trying to run a simple test macro using a vbscript, and I'm getting this error: "Cannot run the macro 'Test'.  The macro may not be available in this workbook or all macros may be disabled."

Here is the text in the vbscript:

```
Dim objExcel, xlBook

Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set xlBook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open("S:\Water\ProcedureSheet.xlsm")

objExcel.visible = True
objExcel.Run "Test"

xlbook.Save
xlbook.Close
objExcel.Quit
```

When executing this, the workbook is opening just fine, so the path specified above is correct.  In this workbook, I have a Module named Test that holds the following macro:

```
Public Sub Test()

    With Sheet3
        Cells(1, 1).Value = Time()
    End With

End Sub
```

Pretty simple, right?  I've checked the vbscript text many times for spelling errors, and I've enabled 'Trust access to the VBA project object model' in the Trust Center settings.  I've even enabled all macros automatically.  I'm not sure what's going wrong here.  Somebody else on this forum mentioned needing to run the vbscript as an administrator in order for it to work?  Since I'm on a work computer I don't have administrator privileges on this system so I can't try it.

Does anyone have any ideas?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It is working for me, after a few changes to your Public Sub Test, the With portion you wrote looks like Pseudocode instead of "correct code".

Also, Time() is not a valid function, it will return an Empty value, you must use the "Now" function to get the Current Time and/or Date

```
'VBScript
Dim objExcel, xlBook

Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set xlBook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open("\\DrivePath\Test.xlsm")

objExcel.visible = True
objExcel.Run "Test"

xlbook.Save
xlbook.Close
objExcel.Quit

'Excel Sub
Public Sub Test()
    With Sheets("Sheet3")
        .Cells(1, 1).Value = Now
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I have one that works fine, but it has a minor difference.

```
 Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application") 
  Set xlBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("X:\Temp\Tables.xls", 0, false) 
  xlapp.visible = true
  xlApp.Run "UpdateAll"
  xlapp.activeworkbook.close
  xlApp.Quit
```

The "0, False" options shouldn't affect whether the macro runs or not, but who knows?  maybe there's another option in play that defaults in the wrong direction?

Answer (score 0):

I appreciate all the assistance with this question.  I figured out my error after fiddling around for a minute.  In the above example, the Module that the "Test" sub was written in was also named "Test", and that was the reason for the error.

Simply changed the name and fixed the correctly identified pseudocode noted above and the script worked just fine.  I changed the module name back to "Test" to confirm my suspicions, and it was indeed the module name that caused that error to be thrown.